# Switching from google-app-engine to firebase-hosting causes cors errors for google-file-storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, firebase-hosting

After switching from app-engine to firebasehosting i get the following error for every file uploaded on the app-enggine version on localhost and production:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKETNAME/uploads%2Fcompress%40_1566757062038_IMG201906.webp?GoogleAccessId=PROJECTID%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=16730323200&Signature=SIGNATURE' from origin 'https://DOMAINNAME' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The bucked has the following cors settings:

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"], "origin": ["*"]}]
```

All files are requested with a signed url generated in the backend like this:

```
const config = {
   action: 'read',
   expires: '03-01-2500',
};
const [thumbFileUrl] = await bucket.file(PATH).getSignedUrl(config);
```

Request in the frontend is done by

```
<img [src]="upload.DownloadUrl" crossorigin="anonymous" >
```

New Uploads are working fine. Just the ones before the switch cause the error.

also set this in the firebase hosting config

```
"hosting": {
"public": "dist/browser",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
],
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "source": "**/*.@(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```